# How to deploy Angular app to weblogic server in a WAR/EAR

Tags: angular, maven, weblogic, weblogic12c

I'm trying to deploy a Angular application into a WeblogicApplication server.

Unfortunately that is not working.

What I do is:
1) Build my Angular application (exec-maven-plugin) and but the result into the "/dist" folder
2) Building a WAR file containng the "/dist"  folder (maven-war-plugin)
So that I have a plain War file with the distfolder inside on the root level (no xml files).
3) Building a EAR file (maven-ear-plugin) with:

```
   <modules>
       <webModule>
           <groupId>com.example.test</groupId>
           <artifactId>angular-app</artifactId>
           <contextRoot>angular-app</contextRoot>
       </webModule>
   </modules>
```

so I get a EAR file containing the war file and in the application.xml:

```
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>angular-app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>angular-app</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
```

but when I try to open the application I only get a "Not found" page or a "Error 404--Not Found"
  no matter what URL:

```
  hostname:8080/angular-app/dist/index.html
  hostname:8080/dist/index.html
```

or other combinations

What do I have to do to make the angular application available?

Edit: First I copied the file via SCP to the server and than via web console deployed the file.

Comment: How did you deploy your application in your weblogic server domain ? By default WebLogic uses port 7001 and not 8080. Is there any confusion in your setup ?

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin: This is just a matter of configuration on the Weblogic Server (an working for other Instances/deployments for me - so that shouldn't be the problem)

Comment: How did you deploy your application ?

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin: I did it via the web console after coping the file to the server.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are using the **base-href** and **deploy-url** parameters
for your case it would be

```
ng build --base-href /angular-app/ --deploy-url /angular-app/
```

The create WEB-INF folder inside the **dist//** folder
in WEB-INF folder create web.xml and weblogic.xml
use the standard conventions

Answer (score 0):

```
1. create a empty spring boot project with war configuration and use the below code to copy dist folder of anugalr app.

deploy the war to weblogic.

<build>
        <finalName>WarName</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>dist/npr</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```